# How to push items from orderBy method to the Firestore database in the same order?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of user posts with documents that contain unique id's. In each document is a timestamp created by the server. To visualize the structure looks like this:

> userPosts (collection) -> uniqueID (document) -> timeStamp (field)

There are around 100 or so uniqueID's with different timeStamp values. I have queried and ordered my data by the timeStamp field, using `.orderBy()` and have the ordered results and wish to write to a document in another collection called "mostRecent" with roughly this structure:

> mostRecent (collection) -> recentTwenty(document) -> posts (array of maps)

```
await db.collection(userPosts)
.orderBy("timeStamp").limit(20).get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.docs.map((item,key) => {
               console.log(item.data())
               db.collection("mostRecent").doc("recentTwenty")
                 .update(
                    {
                      posts: FieldValue.arrayUnion(item.data())
                    },
                    { merge: true }
                  )
            }
     });
```

When `console.log(item.data)` the data is correctly ordered by the timestamp field. However, when I call `.update()` with the correctly ordered items in item.data() to the recentTwenty doc the order is completely out of whack. I would love to understand what is going on. Thanks in advance for whoever helps me out!

Comment: How are you examining this "order"?  The only inherent "order"in Firestore is the documentId's, and *those* should be as random as possible for best performance.  "order" should be imposed by your query, whether a ```.orderBy()```, or in the client, using field data.

Comment: @LeadDreamer I was unclear in describing the ordering. My data is not innately ordered they are randomized by their documentID. I've used the .orderBy() as a query to get a list of 20 documents ordered by their timestamp. Hope that clears it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are NOT waiting for each `.update()` to complete - it IS an asynchronous operation.  Whether it works at ALL also depends on what code you're running outside of what you show - I see no proof that the operations are guaranteed to be competed.  The OUTER `await` doesn't guarantee the synchronicity of the INNER loop.

Firestore arrays ARE ordered by the order they were inserted (if that's how you create them) -but the order the DATABASE will see the operations, as you have shown it here, will depend on Network conditions, etc - you've set up a race condition.  At a MINIMUM, you need to await the result of EACH `.update()` operation to get them in sequence.

A bigger question, though, is WHY use individual `.update()` at all?  Just collect your information using the .map, and write the array in a single operation:

```
await db.collection(userPosts)
.orderBy("timeStamp").limit(20).get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
            //the following .map() is SYNCHRONOUS
            let result_array = querySnapshot.docs.map((item,key) => {
               console.log(item.data())
               return item.data();
            });
            //return the PROMISE from the .set(), for the OUTER await
            return db.collection("mostRecent").doc("recentTwenty")
                 .set(
                    {
                      posts: result_array;
                    },
                    { merge: true }
                  )
     });
```

a single write to the database (which is less expensive)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the `map` runs over a callback function and in your case it is a function with an asynchronous `.update()` function call. Therefore, you will be never be able to be 100% sure that this will be in order. For that you need the execute them in a synchronous call in `for` loop.

```
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.collection("mostRecent").doc("recentTwenty")
      .update(
        {
          posts: FieldValue.arrayUnion(item.data())
        },
        { merge: true }
      )
      .then((result) => resolve(result))
      .catch((err) => reject(err))
    ;
  });
};

await db.collection(userPosts)
  .orderBy("timeStamp").limit(20).get()
  .then(async (querySnapshot) => {
    for(let i = 0; i < querySnapshot.docs.length; i++) {
      await updateItem(querySnapshot.docs[i]);
    }
  })
;
```

You could also find a way to bulk update all the `querySnapshot.docs` in a single operation, which would have a better performance. However, I don't know firebase very well so I can't help you on this.